# MySql workbench - cursors

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Why can't I do this? I want to search for the nearest value greater than the value of my cursor from TABLEA, perform an averaging function on the two and put the result in test3. I get the error code 1054 Unknown column 'Xnearest in 'field list'. Following code is from my procedure:

```
    BEGIN
     #THIS DOES NOT WORK Unknown column Xnearest in field list, error, 
      # declare local variables
     Declare done boolean default 0; 
     Declare xval double; 
     declare i integer default 1;
     Declare Xnearest double;
     Declare polypoint double;

     #declare the cursor
     Declare rows cursor for Select x from TABLE_A;
     #declare continue handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1; #SQL state look through table until no more rows
     # create a table for results if non exists
     CREATE TABLE IF Not Exists test3  (Row_no integer, x_val double, X_Nearest double, x_greater double);
     #OPEN THE CURSOR
     OPEN rows;
     # tell it to loop through all rows
     repeat
     #get x value
     FETCH rows into xval;

    SET Xnearest = (select x from TABLEA where x>xval order by x asc limit 1);
    Set polypoint = xval+abs(xval-Xnearest)/2;

     Insert into test3 (Row_no, x_val,Xnearest,polypoint) Values (i,xval,X_Nearest,x_greater);
     set i=i+1; 


      UNTIL done END REPEAT;
     #close the cursor
     CLOSE rows;
     End
```

Comment: You declared a table `test3` that includes a column `X_Nearest` (with an underscore in the name), then you INSERT into the table and name a column `XNearest` in the column list. The names do not match.

Comment: I think you need to read carefully some reference about the syntax for the INSERT statement, until you understand that the first parenthesized list is for column names, and the second list (after VALUES) is for values.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I'm learning a lot very fast and I mixed up the syntax! It works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor mix up of syntax, Code now works!

```
    BEGIN
    #example cursor attempt to travel through each row at a time, but this time while performing a function and putting result in a new table
     # declare local variables
     Declare done boolean default 0; 
     Declare xval double; 
     declare i integer default 1;
     Declare Xnearest double;
     Declare polypoint double;

     #declare the cursor
     Declare rows cursor for Select x from TABLEA;
     #declare continue handler
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1; #SQL state is an error code, so look through table until no more rows, which applied for this error code
    # create a table for results if non exists
     CREATE TABLE IF Not Exists test3  (Row_no integer, x_val double, X_Nearest double, x_greater double);
    #OPEN THE CURSOR
     OPEN rows;
     # tell it to loop through all rows
     repeat
     #get x value
     FETCH rows into xval;

    SET Xnearest = (select x from TABLEA where x>xval order by x asc limit 1);
    Set polypoint = xval+abs(xval-Xnearest)/2;

     Insert into test3 (Row_no, x_val, X_nearest, x_greater) Values (i,xval,Xnearest,polypoint);
     set i=i+1; 


     UNTIL done END REPEAT;
     #close the cursor
     CLOSE rows;
    End
```